# Run Java program from NodeJS

Tags: java, node.js

I have a VPS running unders CentOS 6.7.

In PHP I run the java program on the server as below:

```
 exec('java -cp "com.opendoorlogistics.connect.jar:com.opendoorlogistics.studio.jar" com.opendoorlogistics.connect.CommandLine -rb batchfile.odlbat', $result);
if(end($result) === 'Finished'){
echo "program run with success";
}
```

I moved my application to NodeJS and I tried to run the program as below:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log("Tester Route");
    var child = spawn('java', ['-cp', '"com.opendoorlogistics.connect.jar:com.opendoorlogistics.studio.jar" com.opendoorlogistics.connect.CommandLine', '-rb batchfile.odlbat']);
    console.log(child);
    res.render('tester');
});

module.exports = router;
```

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var tester = require('./routes/tester');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);

app.use('/tester', tester);


// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});


module.exports = app;
```

I don't see anything on my console except the following:

Tester Route
GET /tester 500 23.291 ms - 1

Any help please how I can run my program ?

Thanks

Comment: Where's the rest of your Express code to make the route actually work?  And, do you know of the router handler is even getting called?  Did you put a `console.log(...)` before the call to `spawn()`?  These are basic debugging steps to troubleshoot where the issue is that you should do an report on before posting here.

Comment: I have updated my post and yes the route is working the console.log() shows before the spawn but the java program is not working I think it is about the synthax : var child = spawn('java', ['-cp', '"com.opendoorlogistics.connect.jar:com.opendoorlogistics.studio.jar" com.opendoorlogistics.connect.CommandLine', '-rb batchfile.odlbat']);